# How to end a congratulation message, beside the 'Congratulations!'?

Tags: writing

I just learned that ELL is going to be one year old soon (January 23, 2014, 19:00 GMT). So I would like to write a congratulation message to ELL. For example,

> ELL is a great place for me to learn English. The community is always helping out. I am certain that my English has been improved noticeably since the time I joined the community. It is great to meet nice people here, be helped, and be able to help others in return. I wish the community to keep growing and thriving strong through this whole year. And not just this year, but also the next years to come.
>
> Congratulations!!!

I feel that *Congratulations!* sounds good, but it's a little typical. So I'm looking for other possible alternatives, that also sound nice, and make a good impression both for the community and myself. What are the alternatives I can use here?

Thank you!

Comment: In the spirit of further help, I recommend you take a second look at “very warmth welcoming.” Also, the definite article before “alternatives” suggests (improperly, imo) that there is a finite, comprehensive list you are hoping to receive.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Thank you very much. I agree with the definite article, and will fix it soon. About "very warmth welcoming", I perhaps misunderstood its meaning but I have no clue. Any recommendation for a fix? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Immediate excision or replacement with “some”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Onwards (and upwards)!
- [an expression from your native tongue]
- Happy helping!
- May your questions be clear and your answers illuminating!
- Let's graduate!

Answer (score 1):

> Congratulations!!!
>
> All the best,
>
> *Signature*

*All the best* is nice because it expresses a message of goodwill for the future. If you wanted to make it more personal, you could say,

> Congratulations! Here's to another fantastic year!

which expresses the same idea but more explicitly, or

> Congratulations! Keep up the good work!

which makes it more personal to the moderators of ELL (if that's who you're addressing this too) and acknowledges their contribution. But if you're just using this as a general message *to the site* this wouldn't be so appropriate (unless you finished the message with *Keep up the good work, mods!* or something).